# Return Value of full Regex match (multiple pattern)

Tags: java, regex

I´m currently working with logs and need to extract Pattern from it. 
I found out that i can concat multiply pattern with the `|` operator.

Quick example:
Pattern 1 : Tree
Pattern 2 : Show

```
String pattern = "Key\\s=\\s<[a-zA-Z0-9]*>|\\[something\\s\\]*";
Pattern.compile(pattern)
```

And I wanna only the result if the String matches the pattern.

With

```
while (matcher.find()) {
            foundValue = matcher.group(0);
        }
```

What I´m getting in result is all groups. So Some single Tree ,some single Show and then some results where both exists.(Even some Blanks?!)

output:

```
[something ]
"heres a blank line why"
key = dataIwantToo
```

How you see i get my pattern but they are split in multply lines.What I want is the result as a whole.
Example:

```
[something ] key = dataIwantToo
```

Is there ans possibility?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Best with a real-life example.

Comment: Maybe include code for your pattern.

Comment: It is not really clear where your problem is. Try to give "this is my input", "this is my code", and "this is the expected output", "this is real output". And you know ... did you read the tons and tons of examples and tutorials that nicely outline how to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation for `Matcher#group`

```
    Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("(tree)|(bush)");
    String test = "These are trees and bushes or even the rare treebush";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while(m.find()){

        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));

    }
```

The output of this is:

```
tree
tree
null
bush
null
bush
tree
tree
null
bush
null
bush
```

To get the matcher to match both you'd need a different regex. For example

```
    Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("(tree(bush)?+)|(bush)");
    String test = "These are trees and bushes or even the rare treebush";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    System.out.println("  0 \t  1 \t  2 \t  3 \t");
    while(m.find()){

        System.out.println(m.group(0) + "\t"
            + m.group(1) + "\t"
            + m.group(2) + "\t"
            + m.group(3)
        );
    }
```

The output is:

```
  0       1       2       3     
tree    tree    null    null
bush    null    null    bush
treebush    treebush    bush    null
```

Note that there are extra groups. It might be best to name your groups. Also somebody might come along with a better regex, especially if you can make some genuine inputs.

Comment: okay thanks. Do you have a quick example? Right now I capsulated my pattern in groups. I know both groups are in my input. Still getting wierd ouput : key= <LRE6000>null
null[something ]
key= <M3P6000>null

Comment: @Offset I would need to see the actual pattern you are using, then the input and output you want.

Comment: I´m Sorry but i cant post the input. I´ll try explaining again. I have logs which have not the same structure. I want to pass a Set of pattern and the programm checks if the  patterns match the line. Example input line: [Tree] [Car] [Flowers]. I pass the regex for Tree and Flower. And get the this Output : [Tree] [Flower]. These pattern I tryed to pass concated via "|". Even after capsulating into groups I cant get the output. Its always [null] [Flower] OR [Tree] [null]. But I know they are in the same line.

Comment: You could use another group, eg. `"(tree(bush)?+)|(bush)"`. When you start gettting nested groups you might want to make a named group just for clarity.

Comment: Ok. I see that could work. But image you have more pattern. like a line of date timestamp key1=value1 key2=value2 ... this gonna be a huge regex. My thought was to save the pattern e.g. key1=value1 and let the user decide which pattern he want to use. It could be only date but in worst case all of them. In ohter words do this dynamic .

Comment: Maybe you don't reg-ex. If it is key/value, maybe you should parse it into a map. eg. `Map<String, String>`